# How to Check List of SQL Servers Online/Offline Status through SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Need to create SSIS package that reads from SQL table (List of SQL Server Name\Instance Name, port -hard coded) and test connection online\offline. If online pass but if offline send email the list of specific offline SQL Servers to user group.

So package consist of 3 steps:

1. Read from SQL Table (List of SQL Server Name\Instance, port)
2. Connect SQL Server Name\Instance to check Online\Offline Status and loop through list of SQL Servers in SQL Table.
3. Send email to user group only offline SQL Servers.

I need help in Step 2.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What errors, if any, are you getting?

Comment: Is the server you are wanting to run this on also one of the servers you need to check? Seems to me this is likely the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: SSIS is not the tool for this. At all. Look into Powershell. SSIS is for data integrations/ETL, moving data from point A to B and perhaps performing some transformations during the move. That is obviously not the case in what you're trying to do.

Powershell, on the other hand, can easily do what you want. Just create your server/database tables, and then build a script to pull them out, loop through them testing the connection

Comment: @SeanLange: No, SSIS package will run on SSIS server which will test connection to other listed SQL Servers in SQL table on same SSIS server.

Comment: @BeardOfTriumph: I can use Powershell as 'Script Task' in SSIS package, would you mind to share the Powershell script which can loop through and try to connect listed SQL table servers.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg: I have completed step 1 and 3 of above SSIS package, I need help in only Step 2 of the package process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a script task (using a loop through a table db server instances) where I try to connect to the database using a try catch. If you cannot connect you will fall into the catch where you would mark the server you just tried to connect to as unavailable.